# Error Overfull \hbox (99.30579pt too wide) in paragraph

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am doing this research paper and this citation keeps bringing up this error.
This is the .bbl file.

```
\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Kamenica%
}{%
Kamenica%
}{%
{\protect \APACyear {2017}}%
}]{%
kamenica_2017}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
kamenica_2017}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Kamenica, E.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{2017}{}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {Information Economics.} {Information economics.}{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\APACjournalVolNumPages{Journal of Political Economy}{125}{6}{1885 - 1890}.
\newblock
\begin{APACrefURL}
\url{http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&db=bsh&AN=126631158&site=ehost-live}
\end{APACrefURL}
```

And here is the .bib

```
@misc{avery_2012, title={Entropy and Economics},url={http://www.cadmusjournal.org/node/146}, journal={Entropy and Economics | Cadmus Journal}, author={Avery, John Scales}, year={2012}, month={Apr}} 
@article{12663115820171201,
Abstract = {The article focuses on the area of information economics as covered in articles published in the "Journal of Political Economy." Topics discussed include the article "The Economics of Information," by George Stigler, incidence of the phrases "information economics" and "economics of information" normalized by the use of the word "economics" in books published from 1900 to 2008 and the asymmetric information revolution.},
Author = {Kamenica, Emir},
ISSN = {00223808},
Journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
Keywords = {Information theory in economics, Econometrics, Information theory, Economics, Journal of Political Economy (Periodical)},
Number = {6},
Pages = {1885 - 1890},
Title = {Information Economics.},
Volume = {125},
URL = {http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&db=bsh&AN=126631158&site=ehost-live},
Year = {2017},
```

}

This is the paper template I was uploading citations to:

```
\section{Introduction}

 Your introduction goes here! Some examples of commonly used commands and features are listed below, to help you get started. \cite{12663115820171201}

 If you have a question, please use the support box in the bottom right of the screen to get in touch. \cite{avery_2012} 


 \bibliographystyle{apacite}
 \bibliography{Economics}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you load the `xurl` package?

Comment: @Mico Lemme try that

Comment: @Mico you should post that as an answer, by the way how do you know which packages to use?

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky - Queries about introducing linebreaks in URL strings come up frequently. I've closed your query as a duplicate of an earlier one.